# How do I redirect Mobile users who click on a link to another link while desktop user go to the same link they clicked on?

Tags: php, url, redirect, mobile, user-agent

Say I have a link that is “link.com/page”.

I want desktop users who click the above link to go to “link.com/page”, but mobile users or tablet users to go to “link.com/differentpage” or even “differentlink.com”.

Is this something to be done in code like php? Can it be done through htaccess?

Can I detect user agent from mobile/tablets and or screen resolution to redirect them to other page?

By the way, the original link “link.com/page” and “link.com/differentpage” will have nothing in common and will be entirely different. And it MUST happen without mobile user first seeing the original link “link.com/page” only to then be redirected to “link.com/differentpage” after they already saw the contents of the original link.

Is this done through code or htaccess or both? Will it work 100% of the time (what I really need is 100% of the time desktop users who click link are not redirected). I just need mobile to go to a different page.

Do I have to detect user agent or resolution of screen or both? I need basically 100% guaranteed success rate.

Comment: You can detect the user agent in php- that's easy to Google. Just remember that user agents are complicated, sometimes change, and are easily spoofed. It's unclear why you would want to treat your users so completely differently just because they are on a different device. Has the principle of responsive design not reached your site yet?

Comment: Hey. It has nothing to do with responsiveness. My site is already responsive. It’s for another reason, and I’mnot worried about user agent being spoofed. And let’s say I was, could I also use screen resolution to redirect mobile users?

Comment: Not on the server side you couldn't, no, that could only be done with javascript. Besides, screen resolution is not the same as the browser window size anyway. And that cannot be detected by the server either. I would be intrigued to know the reason for doing this as it doesn't appear to make sense, with the limited explanation so far. It smells like an XY problem...why do you need to do this? I am wondering if actually there would be a better approach to the overall problem.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just have two links on your page and hide one depending on the screen width of the user with CSS?

Note that since the SO code snippets are displayed in `iframes` the screen width will be based on the width of the `iframe`.

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 767px){
  .mobile-link{
    display: none;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
  .desktop-link{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="mobile-link">Mobile link</a>

<a href="#" class="desktop-link">Desktop link</a>
```

Comment: No. This isn’t the solution I require since the link won’t be clicked from a page (that I control).